# Devise strong parameters not working?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I have being following all the instructions from Devise github's but on sign up it is giving warning

> WARNING: Can't mass-assign protected attributes for User: email, password, password_confirmation

here are my code snippets

RegistrationController

```
class RegistrationController < Devise::RegistrationsController

    private

    def account_update_params
        params.require(:user).permit( :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :current_password)
  end

  def sign_up_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation)
  end

end
```

Comment: You're using the `protected_attributes` gem as well.

Comment: @sevenseacat yes I was using that got fixed thanks mate